# Как создать копию сайта с измененным дизайном?

Tags: парсер

Поясню вопрос:

Допустим у меня есть страница, в iframe которой грузится сайт

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Винтовые сваи Сергиев Посад</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.ya.ru"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Моя цель - визуально изменить элементы сайта, который подгружается в iframe, сохранив при этом функциональность сайта. И это можно было бы с делать с помощью jQuery, но кроссдоменная политика запрещает это.

С помощью каких инструментов я могу реализовать подобное? Возможно посоветуете фреймворк на PHP для этих целей или еще какие то методы.

Answer (score 1):

Для парсинга сайта есть хорошая библиотека [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).